# How to dynamically change attributes of an Enum class in python?

Tags: python, enums

I have an Enum class in python. somthing like this.

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    attribute1 = "alpha/path/to/data1/"
    attribute2 = "alpha/path/to/data2/"
```

in this class, "alpha" is hard-coded.
but now I have a variable called ENVIRONMENT that its value is "alpha" or "beta"
I want to use this variable in MyEnum attributes.
how can I do this?

I searched and I found `DynamicClassAttribute` class. but I didn't know how to use that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a DynamicClassAttribute and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040996/what-is-a-dynamicclassattribute-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Is `ENVIRONMENT` intended to be constant at runtime, or is it expected to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
I overrode the `value` method of the Enum class and inside that I changed the value.

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    attribute1 = "{}/path/to/data1/"
    attribute2 = "{}/path/to/data2/"

    @DynamicClassAttribute
    def value(self):
        return self._value_.format(ENVIRONMENT)
```

Comment: @user2357112 what is the difference in both answers!

Answer (score -2):

try this ruff notion

```
from enum import Enum, DynamicClassAttribute

ENVIRONMENT = "alpha"

class MyEnum(Enum):
    @DynamicClassAttribute
    def attribute1(cls):
        return f"{ENVIRONMENT}/path/to/data1/"

    @DynamicClassAttribute
    def attribute2(cls):
        return f"{ENVIRONMENT}/path/to/data2/"
```

if you use the @DynamicClassAttribute decorator, you can define methods in your Enum class that will be called dynamically to assign values to the attributes. These methods will receive the class (i.e., cls) as a parameter, and you can access the ENVIRONMENT variable within these methods.

You will get the values based on the ENVIRONMENT variable. For example:

```
print(MyEnum.attribute1.value)  # Output: alpha/path/to/data1/
print(MyEnum.attribute2.value)  # Output: alpha/path/to/data2/
```

Comment: Try first and than give down points

Comment: This doesn't work at all. `DynamicClassAttribute` doesn't work like what you describe (plus you're not supposed to import it from `enum` anyway - it's something `enum` imports from `types` for its own internal use, not part of `enum`'s public API).